# Как обновлять конкртеную часть html страничке в цикле?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5, веб-программирование

У меня возникла задача обновлять image в цикле, я абсолютный новичок и понятия не имею как это сделать, знаю только что js + ajax. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> image</title>
    <script>
      document.read(function(){
        $("#frame")
      })

    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
<<image src="/home/anton/frame.jpg" alt="image" id= "frame">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: изменить ссылку или добавить новые?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, изоражения в файле, на который ссылается scr постоянно меняется, нужно обновлять конкретно окошко с картинкой, чтоб изменения отображались и в браузере

Comment: Вам надо обновлять с какой-то периодичностью?

Comment: @Denis640Kb,  можно просто в цикле

Comment: Дело в том, что если запустится страница. В цикле 3 элемента например, они сразу сменят друг друга и останется последняя картинка. Мне кажется это не совсем то, что Вам требуется.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, можно с переодичностью в 50мс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    let Arr = ['https://netology.ru/backend/uploads/page_assets/images/file/51/css.svg','https://netology.ru/backend/uploads/page_assets/images/file/52/js.svg','https://netology.ru/backend/uploads/page_assets/images/file/53/canvas-1.svg'];

    let i = 0;
    function f() {
        if (i<Arr.length) {
            var c = Arr[i];
            var elem = document.getElementById('frame');
            elem.src = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    setInterval(f, 500);
```

```html
<head>
    <title> image</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<image src="https://netology.ru/backend/uploads/page_assets/images/file/50/html.svg" alt="image" id= "frame">
</body>
```

Comment: А зачем нужен массив?

Comment: С обычной картинкой это не работает, она остается статичесной

Comment: @Denver Toha Со статической тоже работает, проверял у себя. Просто необходимо указывать путь от файла вызова. Массив - это аналог данных получаемых через json, чтобы работать в цикле.

Comment: А как это "указывать путь от файла вызова"? Просто путь к файлу?

Comment: Я указал вместо путей к css файлам путь к файлу с картинкой, которая постоянно перезаписывается и соответственно путь к ней в src

Comment: @Denver Toha Верно. Путь указываете таким же образом, как у Вас в изначальном примере. Картинка у Вас перезаписывается одна и та же, с таким же названием?

Comment: да, я указал, не работает

Comment: let Arr = ["/home/anton/frame.jpg", "/home/anton/frame.jpg", "/home/anton/frame.jpg"];
    let i = 0;
    function f() {
        if (i<Arr.length) {
            var c = Arr[i];
            var elem = document.getElementById('frame');
            elem.src = c;
            i++;
        }
    }
    setInterval(f, 50);

Comment: @Denver Toha Так у Вас одна и та же картинка перезаписывается, но очень быстро )

Comment: Работает программа, которая перезаписывает кадр в этом файле, если обновлять страничку вручную, кадры меняются

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104716/discussion-between-denis640kb-and-denver-toha).